# How can we rigorously define a function that maps sets to sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose the function $f(S)=S\cup \{x\}$ where $x$ is an arbitrary element of $S^{\text c}$.

How can this function be defined? In other words, what should $?$ be in $f:?\to ?$, because there is no a set of all sets.

Comment: Functions need a domain which is a set. Nevertheless we can define operations on the class of all sets. Examples: $x\mapsto\{x\}$, $x\mapsto x\cup\{x\}$, $x\mapsto\cup x$ and $x\mapsto\wp(x)$. Every operation goes along with a logical statement in which $x$ is a free variable. Something like $s\mapsto s\cup\{x\}$ where $x$ denotes an "arbitrary set not in $s$" cannot go along with such a statement.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, there is no such thing as "a set of all sets", which means you will have to decide on the *domain* of your function. For example, you could say that $f$ maps $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, or something similar.

---

Your question is actually a good example of why **defining the domain** is an important step in defining the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about $S^\complement$, then $S$ is part of a larger set $X$. So, your function is a function from $\mathcal{P}(X)$ into itself.

Comment: Doesnt the sole existance of $S$ imply that there exists a $S^c$? And what if $X$ is unknown or unbounded?

Comment: @Garmekain No. The notation $S^\complement$ contains the implicit assumption that there is a larger specific set containing $S$ (to which $x$ belongs).

Comment: But every set is a subset of another one, right?

Comment: @Garmekain Right. Every set is a subset of itself, for instance. But, in this case, what is $x$?

Comment: Anything not in $S$, for example, $P(S)$

Comment: @Garmekain saying "anything" not in $S$ is ill defined - you **need** the superset to be defined before you can say $S^c$.

Comment: Supose that that $x=P(S)$ in the question, clearly the function exists for all $S$. But it seems the domain of it cannot be defined. So the function cannot exist, but it is a contradictoon.